# SQLAlchemy: Query filter including extra data from association table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build an ORM mapped SQLite database. The conception of the DB seems to work as intended but I can't seem to be able to query it properly for more complex cases. I have spent the day trying to find an existing answer to my question but nothing works. I am not sure if the issue is with my mapping, my query or both. Or if maybe querying with attributes from a many to many association table with extra data works differently.

This the DB setup:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    # Columns
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    first = Column('first_name', String(100))
    last = Column('last_name', String(100))
    age = Column('age', Integer)
    quality = Column('quality', String(100))
    unit = Column('unit', String(100))

    # Relationships
    cases = relationship('UserCaseLink', back_populates='user_data')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User(first='{self.first}', last='{self.last}', quality='{self.quality}', unit='{self.unit}')>"


class Case(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cases'

    # Columns
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    num = Column('case_number', String(100))
    type = Column('case_type', String(100))

    # Relationships
    users = relationship('UserCaseLink', back_populates='case_data')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Case(num='{self.num}', type='{self.type}')>"


class UserCaseLink(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users_cases'

    # Columns
    user_id = Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    case_id = Column('case_id', Integer, ForeignKey('cases.id'), primary_key=True)
    role = Column('role', String(100))

    # Relationships
    user_data = relationship('User', back_populates='cases')
    case_data = relationship('Case', back_populates='users')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all()
    session = Session()
```

and I would like to retrieve all the cases on which a particular person is working under a certain role.
So for example I want a list of all the cases a person named 'Alex' is working on as an 'Administrator'.
In other words I would like the result of this query:

```
SELECT [cases].*,
       [main].[users_cases].role
FROM   [main].[cases]
       INNER JOIN [main].[users_cases] ON [main].[cases].[id] = [main].[users_cases].[case_id]
       INNER JOIN [main].[users] ON [main].[users].[id] = [main].[users_cases].[user_id]
WHERE  [main].[users].[first_name] = 'Alex'
AND [main].[users_cases].[role] = 'Administrator';
```

So far I have tried many things along the lines of:

```
cases = session.query(Case).filter(User.first == 'Alex', UserCaseLink.role == 'Administrator')
```

but it is not working as I would like it to.

How can I modify the ORM mapping so that it does the joining for me and allows me to query easily (something like the query I tried)?

Answer (score 1):

According to your calsses, the quivalent query for:

```
SELECT [cases].*,
       [main].[users_cases].role
FROM   [main].[cases]
       INNER JOIN [main].[users_cases] ON [main].[cases].[id] = [main].[users_cases].[case_id]
       INNER JOIN [main].[users] ON [main].[users].[id] = [main].[users_cases].[user_id]
WHERE  [main].[users].[first_name] = 'Alex'
AND [main].[users_cases].[role] = 'Administrator';
```

is

```
cases = session.query(
    Case.id, Case.num,Cas.type,
    UserCaseLink.role
    ).filter(
    (Case.id==UserCaseLink.case_id)
    &(User.id==UserCaseLink.user_id)
    &(User.first=='Alex')
    &(UserCaseLink.role=='Administrator'
    ).all()
```

also, you can:

```
cases = Case.query\
    .join(UserCaseLink,Case.id==UserCaseLink.case_id)\
    .join(User,User.id==UserCaseLink.user_id)\
    .filter( (User.first=='Alex') & (User.first=='Alex') )\
    .all()
```

Good Luck

**After comment**

based in your comment, I think you want something like:

```
cases = Case.query\
    .filter( (Case.case_data.cases.first=='Alex') & (Case.case_data.cases.first=='Alex') )\
    .all()
```

where `case_data` connect between `Case` an `UserCaseLink` and `cases` connect between `UserCaseLink` and `User` as in your relations.

But,that case causes error:
`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with dimpor.org_type has an attribute 'org_type_id'`
The missage shows that the attributes combined in filter should belong to the table class

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The second example is already a little bit more concise than the pure SQL query. However this query is litterally an SQLAlchemy translation of the string SQL query. All the joins are already set up in the association table.
Is there no way to set up the mapping such that it could do the joining in the background to get to something like the query I unsuccessfully tried in my original post?
I am trying to make a sort of easily usable API to a DB for users that have very little DB background.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up having to compromise.
It seems the query cannot be aware of all the relationships present in the ORM mapping at all times. Instead I had to manually give it the path between the different classes for it to find all the data I wanted:

```
cases = session.query(Case)\
               .join(Case.users)\
               .join(UserCaseLink.user_data)\
               .filter(User.first == 'Alex', UserCaseLink.role == 'Administrator')\
               .all()
```

However, as it does not meet all the criteria for my original question (ie I still have to specify the joins), I will not mark this answer as the accepted one.